# Unable to refer to resources in webapp struts

Tags: java, web-applications, jboss, struts, war

I have a **struts** based webapp whose **.war** file is deployed on **Jboss EAP** server.

I have a file in **logg.xml** under a project folder `Project_basedir/src/main/resources`.

When I try to get the absolute path of this file logg.xml from any class inside the project, it is trying to search for the file in **server's bin** folder and not in **src/main/resources** folder.

Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

when you package your war the resources will be in WEB-INF/classes.
you shoud get from there not src/main/resources

Comment: But the xml file is not present in WEB-INF/classes folder inside war. It is present at WEB-INF/classes/main/resources. How do I get this xml file to where you are referring.

Comment: something like this this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("logg.xml")

Comment: getResourceAsStream("logg.xml") actually load the properties of file. But that's not what I want. I just need the absolute path of that file logg.xml.

Comment: this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("logg.xml").getPath()

Comment: tried that too. It's searching in WEB-INF/classes folder only not in WEB-INF/classes/*

Comment: you can change path to getResource("main/resources/logg.xml") or in your pom.xml remove tag <resources>

Comment: Why do you want the absolute path? If you're packaging as a WAR file there *is* no "absolute path". Artifacts you need to refer to by absolute path should be located *outside* the web application, and the path configured via a property, a default, a command line arg, etc.